# News email from outlook to Sharepoint news site

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, sharepoint-news

The company that I work with setup an email that functions as news channel that get sent to all staff. Its called email address removed for privacy reasons.

How do I make those emails to populate my SharePoint news site?

Basically like this [RSS feed to SharePoint](https://pnp.github.io/blog/post/use-power-automate-to-automatically-create-sharepoint-news-links/), but for Outlook.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-share-news-on-your-sharepoint-sites-495f8f1a-3bef-4045-b33a-55e5abe7aed7

Use Power Automate:

Create a trigger whenever a new email arrives in your Outlook inbox from your news channel, ‘When a new email arrives’ in the Outlook connector.

Add an action to create a news post in SharePoint and use dynamic content from the trigger to populate these fields. For example, you could use the email subject as the news post title and the email body as the news post content.